# How to add "auto rotate" and rotation direction and speed to a JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript

[CalcPlot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html) is an interactive JavaScript app for plotting math equations. Clicking on the 3D plot window and dragging the mouse on the plot will rotate the surface in the direction you move the mouse about the focus point (the origin, by default). Upon releasing the mouse click the plot will rotate indefinitely.

A script encoding the plot can be created.

My question is this: What text can be added to the script file so that, upon loading the script, the plot is loaded and is rotating in the scripted direction and speed? (I'm not sure if the speed can be set in some fashion as in 'fast' or 'slow' or defined by a 'rotations per minute').

Comment: What have you tried?